# How to center a DIV vertically (that has an auto height) inside a FIXED div

Tags: html, css

Well, that's it. I have some pop ups in my website, and I want them centered in the div that contains it. As I said before, the pop ups' height is set in auto; because each one has a different contain...
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, thanks anyways. I hope this information could help someone else

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```